# Fluctuating Eddystone Beacon Distance

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, beacon, eddystone, google-beacon-platform

Scenario: People wearing beacons are coming from the airport and I am standing at an exit gateway.

Requirement:

1. I only want to view persons within 3-meter.
2. I want to mark the person leaving and for ease I want them to view in a sorted(according to distance) way in my Android application.

Currently facing inconsistency in the distance emitted(Eddystone) by beacons.

Please suggest how to remove noise and get an accurate distance of the beacon or please suggest if there is any other way to do this task.

Comment: i personally feel there is no way to get proper accurate distance, It depends on the things between the mobile and the beacon. Like for example, the distance will be accurate if the mobile and the beacon is in the open environment without any things between them but varies when they are in a very crowded environment.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for distance estimates to fluctuate as radio noise alters the estimate.  Set your expectations appropriately, and this is OK. Larger distance estimates will fluctuate more as there is more noise than signal in the input to the distance estimating algorithm.

If sorting by distance in the UI, your best bet for stability is to first convert the distance to a range of distances (e.g. 0-0.5 meters, 0.5-1 meters,1-3 meters,  3-5 meters, 5-10 meters, 10+ meters).  You can then sort the list to be displayed in the UI by distance range and MAC address.  This will keep the list much more stable.

There will still be variations as beacons move up and down the list, but much less so than when sorting by raw distance estimates.

You can also reduce the fluctuation in your distance estimate by increasing your beacon transmission rate, increasing the power of the transmitter, and adjusting your beacon scanner to average your distance estimate over a longer interval.

Comment: I am using Eddystone beacons (Kontakt) with their SDK to get the distance of the beacon. When I try to increase the transmission power of beacons the distance from SDK is not at all near to the original distance.

Comment: You must re-calibrate the beacon after increasing transmission power.  Kontkt should provide instructions for doing so.